# group by and filter highest value in data frame in scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data like this:

```
a,timestamp,list,rid,sbid,avgvalue
1,1011,1001,4,4,1.20
2,1000,819,2,3,2.40
1,1011,107,1,3,5.40
1,1021,819,1,1,2.10
```

In the data above I want to find which stamp has the highest tag value (avg. value) based on the tag. Like this.

For time stamp 1011 and a 1:

```
1,1011,1001,4,4,1.20
1,1011,107,1,3,5.40
```

The output would be:

```
1,1011,107,1,3,5.40  //because for timestamp 1011 and tag 1 the higest avg value is 5.40
```

So I need to pick this column.

I tried this statement, but still it does not work properly:

```
val highvaluetable = df.registerTempTable("high_value")
val highvalue = sqlContext.sql("select a,timestamp,list,rid,sbid,avgvalue  from high_value")   highvalue.select($"a",$"timestamp",$"list",$"rid",$"sbid",$"avgvalue".cast(IntegerType).as("higher_value")).groupBy("a","timestamp").max("higher_value")
 highvalue.collect.foreach(println)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

After I applied some of your suggestions, I am still getting duplicates in my data.

```
+---+----------+----+----+----+----+
|a| timestamp| list|rid|sbid|avgvalue|
+---+----------+----+----+----+----+
|  4|1496745915| 718|   4|   3|0.30|
|  4|1496745918| 362|   4|   3|0.60|
|  4|1496745913| 362|   4|   3|0.60|
|  2|1496745918| 362|   4|   3|0.10|
|  3|1496745912| 718|   4|   3|0.05|
|  2|1496745918| 718|   4|   3|0.30|
|  4|1496745911|1901|   4|   3|0.60|
|  4|1496745912| 718|   4|   3|0.60|
|  2|1496745915| 362|   4|   3|0.30|
|  2|1496745915|1901|   4|   3|0.30|
|  2|1496745910|1901|   4|   3|0.30|
|  3|1496745915| 362|   4|   3|0.10|
|  4|1496745918|3878|   4|   3|0.10|
|  4|1496745915|1901|   4|   3|0.60|
|  4|1496745912| 362|   4|   3|0.60|
|  4|1496745914|1901|   4|   3|0.60|
|  4|1496745912|3878|   4|   3|0.10|
|  4|1496745912| 718|   4|   3|0.30|
|  3|1496745915|3878|   4|   3|0.05|
|  4|1496745914| 362|   4|   3|0.60|
+---+----------+----+----+----+----+

 4|1496745918| 362|   4|   3|0.60|  
 4|1496745918|3878|   4|   3|0.10|
```

Same time stamp with same tag. This is considered as duplicate.

This is my code:

```
rdd.createTempView("v1")
val rdd2=sqlContext.sql("select max(avgvalue) as max from v1 group by  (a,timestamp)")
rdd2.createTempView("v2")
val rdd3=sqlContext.sql("select a,timestamp,list,rid,sbid,avgvalue from v1  join v2 on v2.max=v1.avgvalue").show()
```

Comment: 1011 is not a timestamp

Comment: No, This is sample data for understanding purpose.Actual data is different

Comment: but please always post sample data at least with the same datatypes. 
answers might differ, if you post wrong data types

Comment: Oh okay sure. The data type is string only. I am casting to integer

Comment: what is your expected result if there are two records, with the same timestamp, same column a AND the same avgvalue too?

Comment: Please don't do this. You are using sql. It's not worth it to load entire table into app memory just to find the highest value record. Do that entirely in sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dataframe` api to find the `max` as below:

```
df.groupBy("timestamp").agg(max("avgvalue"))
```

this will give you output as

```
+---------+-------------+
|timestamp|max(avgvalue)|
+---------+-------------+
|1021     |2.1          |
|1000     |2.4          |
|1011     |5.4          |
+---------+-------------+
```

which doesn't include the other fields you require . so you can use first as

```
df.groupBy("timestamp").agg(max("avgvalue") as "avgvalue", first("a") as "a", first("list") as "list", first("rid") as "rid", first("sbid") as "sbid")
```

you should have output as

```
+---------+--------+---+----+---+----+
|timestamp|avgvalue|a  |list|rid|sbid|
+---------+--------+---+----+---+----+
|1021     |2.1     |1  |819 |1  |1   |
|1000     |2.4     |2  |819 |2  |3   |
|1011     |5.4     |1  |1001|4  |4   |
+---------+--------+---+----+---+----+
```

The above solution would not still give you correct row-wise output so what you can do is use window function and select the correct row as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("timestamp").orderBy("a")

df.withColumn("newavg", max("avgvalue") over windowSpec)
  .filter(col("newavg") === col("avgvalue"))
  .drop("newavg").show(false)
```

This will give row-wise correct data as

```
+---+---------+----+---+----+--------+
|a  |timestamp|list|rid|sbid|avgvalue|
+---+---------+----+---+----+--------+
|1  |1021     |819 |1  |1   |2.1     |
|2  |1000     |819 |2  |3   |2.4     |
|1  |1011     |107 |1  |3   |5.4     |
+---+---------+----+---+----+--------+
```

Comment: I want to select for each timestamps a's highest avgvalue across all the list.

Comment: For some reasons it showing duplicates again.I am getting same timestamp with same a's column.I am not supposed to get.

Comment: what are your groupBy fields? and what are the duplicates? can I see some samples?

Comment: Humm Sure . I will post now

Comment: a and timestamp.

Comment: I tried your's suggestion as well as ishan suggestion.I posted my code.

Comment: I guess you tried Ishan's suggestion. I am not that good with sql queries so I can't really tell the exact problem with your updated code.

Comment: I tried your's also. I added a,timestamp in the partition .

Comment: yeah thats correct. :) try by removing orderBy part.

Comment: then both timestamp should be different. there should empty space in the front or back. it might be the same with `a` column

Comment: try `df.select("a".trim, "timestamp".trim, "list".trim, "rid".trim, "sbid".trim, "avgvalue".trim)` before you apply our solutions then. and let me know. thanks

Comment: Okay got it.Incase If I have same highest values for same a with same timestamps means ??

Comment: The duplicates values comes because of it contains same highest avg values in 2 rows

Answer (score 1):

All the other solutions provided here did not give me the correct answer so this is what it worked for me with *`row_number()`*:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("timestamp").orderBy(desc("avgvalue"))

df.select("a", "timestamp", "list", "rid", "sbid", "avgvalue")
  .withColumn("largest_avgvalue", row_number().over( windowSpec ))
  .filter($"largest_avgvalue" === 1)
  .drop("largest_avgvalue")
```

The other solutions had the following problems in my tests:

- The solution with `.agg( max(x).as(x), first(y).as(y), ... )` doesn't work because `first()` function "*will return the first value it sees*" according to [documentation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L452-L458), which means it is non-deterministic,
- The solution with `.withColumn("x", max("y") over windowSpec.orderBy("m") )` doesn't work because the result of the max will be same as in the value that is selecting for the row. I believe the problem there is the `orderBy()"`.

Hence, the following also gives the correct answer, with *`max()`*:

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("timestamp").orderBy(desc("avgvalue"))
    
df.select("a", "timestamp", "list", "rid", "sbid", "avgvalue")
  .withColumn("largest_avgvalue", max("avgvalue").over( windowSpec ))
  .filter($"largest_avgvalue" === $"avgvalue")
  .drop("largest_avgvalue")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy and find the max value for that perticular group as

```
//If you have the dataframe as df than 

df.groupBy("a", "timestamp").agg(max($"avgvalue").alias("maxAvgValue"))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: humm same timestamp with same tag.

Comment: I should get one timestamp and one a. then corresponding highest avg value.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the above answers. Below is the one which you can try as well

```
val sqlContext=new SQLContext(sc)
case class Tags(a:Int,timestamp:Int,list:Int,rid:Int,sbid:Int,avgvalue:Double)
val rdd=sc.textFile("file:/home/hdfs/stackOverFlow").map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x=>Tags(x(0).toInt,x(1).toInt,x(2).toInt,x(3).toInt,x(4).toInt,x(5).toDouble)).toDF
rdd.createTempView("v1")
val rdd2=sqlContext.sql("select max(avgvalue) as max from v1 group by (a,timestamp)")
rdd2.createTempView("v2")
val rdd3=sqlContext.sql("select a,timestamp,list,rid,sbid,avgvalue from v1 join v2 on v2.max=v1.avgvalue").show()
```

OutPut

```
+---+---------+----+---+----+--------+
|  a|timestamp|list|rid|sbid|avgvalue|
+---+---------+----+---+----+--------+
|  2|     1000| 819|  2|   3|     2.4|
|  1|     1011| 107|  1|   3|     5.4|
|  1|     1021| 819|  1|   1|     2.1|
+---+---------+----+---+----+--------+
```

Comment: For some reasons it showing duplicates again.I am getting same timestamp with same a column.I am not supposed to get.